# computing $\arcsin{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\gamma$ be a straight line from $0$ to $\left(\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4}i\right)$. Find

$$\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$

Express the answer in the form of $a+ib$

My intuition tells me that it has to do something with the principle branch. The integral itself is pretty simple

$$I=\arcsin{z}$$

if we let $\arcsin{z} = \zeta\rightarrow z=\sin{\zeta}$ using the identity $\cos^2{\theta}+\sin^2{\theta}=1$

then $$\cos{\zeta}=\sqrt{1-\sin{\zeta}}$$

$$e^{i\zeta}=\cos{\zeta}+i\sin{\zeta}$$

Finally giving us $$\zeta= 2\pi k-i\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{8}i}+3i/4-1/4\right)$$

and clearly $\arcsin{0}=0$

I have a strong feeling that I'm approaching this problem with the wrong mindset. Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just a very quick answer, you could use the approach outline in this paper: 
http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/arc_10.pdf.

It outlines (from the end of page 4) how to get an equation for arcsin(z),

$arcsin(z) = \frac{1}{i} \text{ln}(iz + |1 - z^2|^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{\frac{i}{2}\text{arg}(1 - z^2)})$.

Comment: Thanks for answering Luke. But how would I end up with a real value with that equation?

Comment: perhaps this could be computed by using residues at infinity?